# Difficult crash on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

This only seems to be occurring on iOS 8 devices.  The stack trace isn't giving me much useful information.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
0     CoreFoundation                        0x23c91c58 CFBasicHashFindBucket + 11816
1     CoreFoundation                        0x23c8edeb CFDictionaryGetValue + 104
2     CFNetwork                             0x237e958d _ZN12SocketStream12copyPropertyEPKvPK10__CFString + 114
3     CoreFoundation                        0x23d64efb CFReadStreamCopyProperty + 108
4     CFNetwork                             0x2382797d _ZN14SPDYConnection10isCellularEv + 26
5     CFNetwork                             0x23827929 _ZN14SPDYConnection15shouldIdleCloseEdd + 58
6     CFNetwork                             0x238366d3 ___ZN24SPDYConnectionCacheEntry15shouldIdleCloseEdd_block_invoke + 32
7     CoreFoundation                        0x23ca73f1 CFArrayApplyFunction + 34
8     CFNetwork                             0x23836695 _ZN24SPDYConnectionCacheEntry15shouldIdleCloseEdd + 134
9     CFNetwork                             0x23897edb _ZN19SPDYConnectionCache29_onqueue_purgeIdleConnectionsEb + 248
10   CFNetwork                              0x237f5189 _ZN19RunloopBlockContext13_invoke_blockEPKvPv + 58
11   CoreFoundation                         0x23ca73f1 CFArrayApplyFunction + 34
12   CFNetwork                              0x237f5043 _ZN19RunloopBlockContext7performEv + 180
13   CFNetwork                              0x237f4f09 _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 214
14   CFNetwork                              0x237f4da5 _ZN17MultiplexerSource8_performEPv + 46
15   CoreFoundation                         0x23d5c5e7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
16   CoreFoundation                         0x23d5b9fb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 220
17   CoreFoundation                         0x23d5a079 __CFRunLoopRun + 766
18   CoreFoundation                         0x23ca7981 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 474
19   CoreFoundation                         0x23ca7793 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
20   CFNetwork                              0x2385c9df +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 484
21   Foundation                             0x24aa799b __NSThread__main__ + 1116
22   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x31cd4e67 _pthread_body + 136
23   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x31cd4ddb _pthread_start + 116
24   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x31cd2b84 thread_start + 6
```

Comment: More information would be helpful - did you create this thread or was it created by another library? What is it's purpose? Did you try compiling with debug information, and/or running under a debugger and walking back up the stack until you hit your code?

Comment: Try enabling NSZombieEnabled and see if this helps.